# Dit-on « Envisager la solution d’un problème sous tous les points de vue » ou « Envisager la solution d’un problème de tous les points... »?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, constructions

J’hésite entre les deux tournures en question. Et aussi, j’hésite entre « envisager la résolution D’un problème » et « envisager la résolution À un problème.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que tu veux dire par là ? "Une solution a été proposée et on envisage de la mettre en œuvre" ou "On analyse un problème sous tous les angles afin d'en chercher une solution" ?

Comment: Salut jilliagre, je voulais dire « On analyse un problème sous tous les angles afin d’en chercher une solution. ». Souvent un problème peut être solutionné de plusieurs manières. C’est souvent le cas en physique. Merci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La première phrase :

> Envisager la solution d'un problème sous tous les points de vue

ne correspond pas à ce que tu attends. Elle signifie qu'une solution existe et qu'on envisage (prudemment?) de la mettre en œuvre.

Remplacer *sous tous les points de vue* par *de tous les points de vue* ne change pas fondamentalement le sens.

Comme tu expliques qu'il s'agit de la recherche d'une solution, le mot *résolution* est plus adapté. En revanche, le verbe *envisager* n'a alors plus beaucoup de sens. Envisager, c'est se demander ce qui se passerait si l'on faisait quelque chose, soupeser le pour et le contre, donc on envisage une solution potentielle, on la retient ou on la rejette et on passe à la solution potentielle suivante. On peut envisager des solutions mais dire qu'on envisage une résolution, ça signifie que l'on estime possible qu'une solution soit trouvée, par que l'on fait la démarche de la trouver, cette solution.

Je pencherais donc plutôt vers:

> Envisager toutes les stratégies pouvant conduire à la résolution d'un problème.

et si tu veux garder la métaphore des points de vue:

> Examiner sous tous les angles le problème pour en trouver la ou les solutions.

Answer (score 0):

"Sous tous les points de vue" n'est plus autant utilisé de nos jours mais fait toujours partie de la langue moderne. On peut donc dire

- "Examiner/considérer/envisager… la solution d'un problème sous tous les points de vue".

En ce qui concerne la préposition "de" on trouve  un exemple récent (2009) dans lequel justement figure le verbe "envisagé"  : [réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=InLc0bWL6kIC&pg=PT29&dq=%22tous+les+points+de+vue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMsrf64dfrAhUU6OAKHfk-D0QQ6AEwTXoECBoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22tous%20les%20points%20de%20vue%22&f=false).

- *La cité opère le passage de l'ésotérique à l'exotérique, du caché au manifeste, dans la mesure où tout ce qui concerne le domaine commun doit être vu de partout, accessible à tous, envisagé de tous les points de vue possibles.*

Les deux formes se valent et peuvent être utilisées sans crainte de faire un faux pas.

On peut donc envisager la solution [sous le/du] point de vue de ne produire que des résultats approximatifs/de la nécessité de résultats rapides, etc.